# Does Using Same Declared Variable Name To Make Calculations Make Sense?

Tags: php, variables

I'm wondering if this following piece of code makes sense from a PHP perspective:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$year = $_POST['year'];
$month = $_POST['month'];

if($month == 'December'){

$month = 'January';

$year = $year + 1;//can this be done?

}
}
```

Comment: You couild've easily tested this.

Comment: Sure why not? Since it's a POST value maybe you should make sure it's a numeric value first. You could also use `$year++;`

Comment: *`//can this be done?`* - Did you try it before posting?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. You could also do:

```
$year++;
or
$year += 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, makes sense and is safe. The right side is evaluated first. There are shortcuts for these operations:

```
A = A op B
A op= B
```

So:

```
$year += 1;
```

And with everything else as well (`-= *= /= .=`). For incrementing a single unit, there is also `$year++` or `$year--` for decrementing, plus the variations `++$year` and `--$year`.

Please check out the manual pages for [Assignment Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) and [Increment Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `+` operator you're telling php to mathematically sum both values, therefore both of them will be parsed as integer (or float) values before actually making the sum. So if `$month`'s value is `"10"` (string), it will be parsed as `10` (integer) and then you will have `10 + 1 = 11`.